# jquery ajax invalid_state_err dom exception 11 phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm new in phonegap developping,I get this error 'invalid_state_err dom exception 11 when i try to make an ajax request and update a dom element, the init function is called in body load, i tried to execute the php page and it works with no problem, this is my code

```
function init(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
// Now safe to use the Cordova API

}
function onOnline(){
loadCategories(5);
}
function loadCategories(id_cat){
$.ajax({

    type : "GET",



    url : 'http://t21copy.info/doc/getCategories.php',

    data : {id_parent:id_cat},

    success : function(data, textStatus) {
    alert('succ '+data);
        $('#catgs').html(data);
    },
    error : function(data,status, error) {
        //alert('d '+data);
        alert(" error "
                + error );

    }
   });
}
```

Comment: you cannot make an ajax call offline to your localhost. it'll work if you actually use it on a domain with real url address!

Comment: where is founashop/getCategories.php hosted? it cant be localhost. If it is on ur personal laptop(running apache server), then you have to use: http://<your_ip_address>/founashop/getCategories.php

Comment: getCategories is located in localhost, in my www in wampserver

Comment: i tried to upload the file in a server and i changed the url but i get the same error also. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I forget to permit access to internet in manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```